# SPSS 24 ftp upload file

Tags: file-upload, ftp, spss

I am using SPSS Statistics 24 and am looking for a solution how to upload a file to ftp server. I have been searching online but can't find any examples.

Many thanks,

Art

Answer (score 0):

Art,

There is nothing in SPSS Statistics to upload/download files to/from an FTP server.  Are you sure you aren't thinking of saving the file (*.sav) locally and then using FTP client software of some kind to upload your file?  If you have previously mounted the FTP resource to your filesystem (e.g. Mapped a drive, using Google Drive, iCloud Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive, etc.) then the normal GET and SAVE operations should apply.  But no, SPSS Statistics itself is not an FTP client.

I hope this helps,

-ddwyer